# How to properly insert rows from Oracle DB into HTML select box

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I am fetching rows from an Oracle table to put them into a select box but the output is not as expected. To give some context, i am querying the database to give me 4 columns of the desired rows to put each row on a single line in the drop menu but instead, i get every column of each row individually on a line. 
I would like to get help on how i could proceed to have each individual row with their 4 columns on a single line.

This is my oracle table from which i am retrieving data:

```
create table TP2_ITEM (
    NO_ITEM number generated always as identity,
    NO_ENCAN number(9) not null,
    NO_ITEM_ENCAN_ITE number(9) not null,
    TITRE_ITE varchar2(50) not null,
    CHEMIN_PHOTO_ITE varchar2(200) default 'N/A',
    DESC_ITE varchar2(200) default 'N/A',
    DONATEUR_ITE varchar2(25) not null,
    MNT_VALEUR_ITE number(8,2) not null,
    MNT_PRIX_DEPART_ITE number(8,2) not null,
    MNT_INCREMENT_MINI_ITE number(8,2) not null,
    MNT_ACHAT_IMMEDIAT_ITE number(8,2) not null,
    EST_FERME_ITE number(1) default 0,
    EST_PAYE_ITE number(1) default 0,
    constraint PK_ITEM primary key(NO_ITEM),
    constraint FK_NO_ENCAN1 foreign key(NO_ENCAN)
    references TP2_ENCAN(NO_ENCAN) on delete cascade,
    constraint AK_ENCAN_ITEM unique(NO_ENCAN,NO_ITEM_ENCAN_ITE));
```

this is the code to fetch my rows and put them into a select box:

````
<?php 
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select I.NO_ITEM, NO_ITEM_ENCAN_ITE, TITRE_ITE, 
                              MNT_VALEUR_ITE from TP2_ITEM I,TP2_ITEM_FAVORI F
                              where NOM_UTILISATEUR = '" .$nom_utilisateur. "' 
                              and F.NO_ITEM = I.NO_ITEM and NO_ENCAN = '" 
                              .implode(',', $no_encan_uti). "'";
    oci_execute($stid);
    echo "<select>";
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo "<option>" .$item. "</option>;
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    oci_free_statement($Stid);
?>
```[![Output from my program][1]][1]
````

P.S. I do not have any errors when i run the program but the result is not what i expect, like i described earlier.

**[This is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeYSA.png) of the result i get with the drop menu.

Comment: To avoid SQL Injection security issues (and for performance) you MUST use [bind variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) instead of  constructs like `NOM_UTILISATEUR = '" .$nom_utilisateur. "'`  Also see  later chapters of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `I.NO_ITEM` is the identifier, and you want to use that field as the value of the option, and the other three as the text, you can do

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC) {

    $value = $row[0];
    $text = $row[1] . ' ' . $row[2] . ' ' . $row[3];

    echo "<option value='$value'>$text</option>"; 

}
```

You don't need to compare a value to `false` in a conditional, is enough to use that value as the condition, if it is `false` the condition fails.

If you check the code you posted, you will also see that you have two sets of parenthesis around the assignment `((while ($row = oci_fetch_array(...))`, but no parethesis after the `!=false` condition and before the `{` so your code probably is not running.